# Memory is not being relased when I go back and forth between view controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller, dealloc

I have an app with a main view controller that has a uitableview that has a user listed in each cell. Each cell has a profile pic. Tapping the profile pic goes to that users profile page using `pushViewController()` and the memory usage increases like normal. The problem is when I go back to the main page, the memory is still very high (I see so in the debug navigator). If click another profile in the main page the memory increases even more, on and on until the app crashes. Please show me where I am messing up.

My Cell Class looks like:

```
class LatestCell: UITableViewCell {
weak var delegate: LatestCellDelegator!    
@objc func profPicClick(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
let tImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
if(self.delegate != nil){
            self.delegate.goToProfilePage(userID: fUserId!,  profileImage: tImage )
        }
}    

//I'm keeping my TableView class separate from My main controller class because I use my tableView everywhere. Just trying to be efficient. It looks like this:

`class ReusableTableView:  NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, LatestCellDelegator {    
     weak var parentCollectionController: UIViewController?
    init(_ tv: UITableView, _ data: [LatestStatus],_ pcc: UIViewController)
    {
        super.init()
        self.tableViewData = data
        self.tableView = tv
        parentCollectionController = pcc
        self.tableView?.register(UINib(nibName: "FreeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "FreeCell")
    }    
    ...
    //Trying to deallocate
    deinit {
        print("deinit is called")
    }    
        ...
        func goToProfilePage(userID dataobjectUID: String, profileImage dataProfileImage: UIImageView) {
        weak var profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RealProfilePage") as? ProfilePage2
        profileVC?.userId = dataobjectUID 
parentCollectionController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileVC!, animated: true)
        profileVC = nil
    }
```

`

This is the Main controller that holds the tableView. As you see below I have MainViewController as one of the parameters for when I instatiate reusableTableView because that is how I am able to call parentCollectionController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(... in the ReusableTableView class:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var theTableview: UITableView!
var usersArray: [Users]?
weak var thisController = self    
override func viewDidLoad() {
reusableTableView = ReusableTableView(theTableview, usersArray!, thisController!)
}
```

and then finally this is the profile page that is shown when a profile pic is clicked

```
class ProfilePage2: UIViewController{
//heavy code is doneby using the userId to show pics and network calls etc
  var userId: String?
    deinit {
        print("deinit is being called in Profile Page")
    }  
//deinit is never called by the app for some reason
```

Memory usage increases when pushViewController() is called but the memory doesnt reduce when the back button is tapped and I go back to the MainController. Memory increases by 20 MB everytime. How can I release the memory properly. Thanks

Comment: Did you try removing `weak var thisController = self` and use `self` only instead of `thisController`?

Comment: Yes, in fact that's what I did at the beginning, but then I added the weak var when I noticed the problems

Comment: @Torongo Yes but it still gave me the same problem

Comment: is your `reusableTableView` declared as a `weak var` if not, that can create this issue?

Comment: You need to provide more code as you are passing the `[User]` from `MainViewController` to `ReusableTableView` but there is no information how you are using that. Similarly, how `reusableTableView` is declared?

Comment: @Kamran ok I will add more code soon and let you know

Comment: @Torongo yep it's declared as weak var reusableTableView: ReusableTableView!

Comment: @Kamran i declare it as weak var reusableTableView: ReusableTableView! .... in Main view controller, these are all the ways i'm using reusabletableview

Comment: Ok, but with the above code its difficult to predict the cause for leak. BTW, do you have memory dump information? Do you know which `class` is not deallocated?  How many instances of that `class` etc?

Comment: @Kamran ProfilePage2 is not being deallocated. I create an instance of ProfilePage when I click on the profile pic

Comment: @Kamran i declare it as weak var reusableTableView: ReusableTableView! .... [User] is only being used in MainViewController and RusableTableView, it is not used in ProfilePage2`